# T-SQL - How to select two columns data of same table by grouping and using two different where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have orders table with two columns sales_amt, Disc_Amt.  I want to find the each month total sales amount having discounts and without discount

Table:

| month | sales_amt | Disc_Amt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jan | 20 |  |
| Jan | 30 |  |
| Feb | 5 | 2 |
| Feb | 30 |  |
| Feb | 10 | 5 |
| Mar | 80 | 10 |
| Mar | 20 |  |

Result required:

| month | Sales_Amount_Without_Discount | Sales_Amount_With_Discount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jan | 50 | 0 |
| Feb | 30 | 15 |
| Mar | 80 | 20 |

I tried with the below query

```
Select 
         month(invoice_date),
         sales_amt as Sales_Amount_Without_Discount,
         Sales_Amount_Without_Discount =  (select  
                                                 sales_amt 
                                           from 
                                                 orders
                                           where
                                                 disc_amt > '0'  
                                           )
from
       orders
Group by 
       month(invoice_date)
```

Currently I am getting result as below

| month | Sales_Amount_Without_Discount | Sales_Amount_With_Discount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jan | 50 | 110 |
| Feb | 30 | 110 |
| Mar | 80 | 110 |

Thank you

Comment: It's easier for us to help when you provide consistent "facts". Your query contains `month(invoice_date)`, but your sample data has no dates. (Nor DDL, so we can only guess that every column is an `NVarChar(MAX)` as evidenced by the string comparison `disc_amt > '0'`.) The "Required result" values are a bit perplexing. `Mar` has `80` sales with a discount of `10` that appears in the `Sales_Amount_Without_Discount` column while the undiscounted `20` is in `Sales_Amount_With_Discount`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by putting a case expression within your `SUM()`, e.g.

```
SELECT  MONTH(invoice_date),
        Sales_Amount_Without_Discount = SUM(sales_amt),
        Sales_Amount_With_Discount = SUM(CASE WHEN Disc_Amt > 0 THEN sales_amt ELSE 0 END)
FROM    orders
GROUP BY
        MONTH(invoice_date);
```

Comment: Thank you this worked for me, can you help how can count the same instead of  SUM. I tried but again I can see the same result  i.e. no. of orders received without discount is display in no. of orders received with discounts.

Comment: You could simply use `COUNT(SUM(CASE WHEN Disc_Amt > 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)`, since `COUNT(*)` ignores nulls this would only count where there is a discount. This could also be made more concise as `COUNT(NULLIF(Disc_Amt, 0))`